# Click on email intent chooser not opening the email app or any of the mail client

Tags: android, android-intent, android-intent-chooser

i just want to send an email with attachments. i just done everything based on the developer site.

https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html

it opening the email intent chooser but when i click on any of the app in chooser it doesn't open any app to send an mail with attachments. any thing i want to add in Android Manifest file.

helps are more appreciated.

and i got message from log too:

```
    06-02 11:49:36.751: W/ContextImpl(16313): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:830 com.samsung.android.share.SShareLogging.insertLog:74 com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity.onTargetSelected:1223 com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity.onTargetSelected:386 com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity.startSelected:1040 
    06-02 11:49:36.771: W/AudioPolicyIntefaceImpl(3069): Skipped to add effects on session 2024
```

Comment: i edited @mdDroid. Can you see it?

Comment: **Paste your sharing code here**..!! That's meaning of **show us what u tried**.

Comment: do you got it fixed @user3546693

Comment: not got fixed and i have one query if file size 0 then cant able to attach rite?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, this may helpful for you

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:" + "" + receiver_mail);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "body");

try {
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email using..."));
} 
catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) 
{
Toast.makeText(ClusteringMinimaTest.this, "No email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Hi ravi. thanks for your reply but we can't use sendto for attachments rite?

Comment: ok... you have any idea why the email client is not getting open when clicking the email client in email intent chooser box?

Comment: i will see and let u know

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for that.

```
       try { 
              final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(
                                     android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
              emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
              emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                                     new String[] { "YOUR_RECIEPINTS" });
              emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                                     "YOUR_SUBJECT");
               if (URI != null) {
                         emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, URI);
               }
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "YOUR_MESSAGE");

             this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent,
                                     "Sending email..."));

         } catch (Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(this,
                                     "Request failed try again: " + t.toString(),
                                     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
```

If it give any permission exception then use below permissions for that,

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: if its two attachments? then?

Comment: then you can use below line,

emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);

Comment: ok and my problem is why i click email client in the client chooser box it doesn't open the any email client simple.

Comment: for that you need to shoe your code here, and also possible permission issue.